# error in your SQL syntax (use select in subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 UNION SELECT * FROM tbl2) ORDER BY xid
```

not working !

result:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

even:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl)
```

Of course, I don't want to use view as much as possible

Comment: No need for a subquery. Do the UNION and have the ORDER BY at the end.

Comment: Each _derived table_ (i.e. FROM clause subquery) needs to be named. E.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) t`.

Comment: You're getting an error related to `LIMIT` because phpMyAdmin adds `LIMIT 0, 25` to the end of every query for pagination of results.